# How to find string between some characters using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Good day~
I am not really good at this regular expression.
So I need your help, please.

Condition:
Users can input their email addressed and name together.
I want to extract email address and user name out of string.

```
string pattern1 = "Peter Jackson<peter@jackson.com>";
```

From that string I want to get "Peter Jackson" and "<peter@jackson.com>".

```
string pattern2 = "Peter Jackson(peter@jackson.com)";
```

However, people always make mistakes like below.

And they can also use "[" instead of "<".
so...

```
string pattern3 = "Peter Jackson[peter@jackson.com]";
```

Even some stupid users can input like...

```
string pattern4 = "Peter Jackson{peter@jackson.com}";
```

So, I had to look for the characters which are "<", "(", "[" and "{".
I tried

```
string regularExpressionPattern = @"^(<|(|[|{)(.*?)^(}|]|)|>)";
```

But I think I've done something wrong.
And I also try to think that people could input more mistake like....

```
string pattern5 = "Peter Jackson<peter@jackson.com>mistake";
```

Could anyone help this problem?
Advanced thanks.

PS: I know how to split string with a character. So it won't help. I needa proper regular expression.

Comment: It would help if you said *what* went wrong. (What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?)

Comment: Why not just ask for their full name and email address as two seperate inputs...?

Comment: @vcsjones Developing is not that simple job to do. Isn't it? ^^;

Comment: @KendallFrey As I mentioned in my question, I expect to abstract people's name and email address like "Peter Jackson" and "<peter@jackson.com>". Even if they write "<", "(", "[" or "[". But with my expression, it returns blank.

Comment: Also, for regex questions, it's very helpful to have either **A.** a list of strings that *should* match the regex, and a list of strings that *should not*, or **B.** A string or list of strings, and a list of the substrings that should match.

Comment: @KendallFrey They are already in my question as pattern1 ~ 5.

Comment: You haven't described exactly what you want to match. You also haven't described the difference between what you expected, and what really happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the regular expression you are looking for is as follows:

```
(.*?)[<([{](.*?)[>)\]}]
```

You would want group 1 and group 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)[([<{](.*?)[)\]>}]
```

I believe this should be adequate.

The name will be in the first captured group, and the email will be in the second.

Comment: Thanks to you, too. It also works. I didn't know about grouping with [].

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `(.*)[<\(\[{](.*)[>\)]}]` works for me.

Groups for the name, and the email address as well.

http://regexr.com?33sq4 is my test.